# UUID::UUID not found in melodic

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS-Community,

I am working my way through the [Wil Selby Quadrotor Simulator](https://github.com/wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator), but I am having some issues here.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic.

I clone all packages as mentioned into my workspace and use catkin_make. I first of all did that after cloning the glog_catking and catkin_simple into my src folder. It runs through.

After I get all the other packages which are mentioned and run catkin_make, thats the error I get:

```
CMake Error at rotors_simulator/rotors_gazebo_plugins/CMakeLists.txt:85 (target_link_libraries):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:UUID::UUID,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "UUID::UUID" not found.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/thorsten/catkin_ws/build
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

There is a lot more of the same errors.

Thanks for any help!

Update: the error changes, when I do the same but as root.

```
/home/thorsten/src/rotors_simulator/rotors_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_octomap_plugin.cpp:25:10: fatal error: gazebo/math/Vector3.hh: No such file or directory
 #include <gazebo/math/Vector3.hh>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314550/uuid::uuid-not-found-in-melodic/) by [cluue](https://answers.ros.org/users/39748/cluue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-03**:
Thi would seem to be an issue with the packages you're trying to build. I would recommend you post this as an issue on their tracker ([this one](https://github.com/wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator/issues)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue on the tracker: [wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator#44](https://github.com/wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator/issues/44).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0